# running test command using lerna managed monorepo using --scope fails

Tags: javascript, npm, lerna, monorepo

I'm using `lerna` to manage my monorepo, for some reason, when I try to run the following command from the root folder ([using the docs here](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/run#readme)): `lerna run --scope my-app test` I get the following error of lerna didn't find the module to run `npm test` on:

```sh
lerna notice cli v3.20.2
lerna info versioning independent
lerna notice filter including "my-app"
lerna info filter [ 'my-app' ]
lerna ERR! EFILTER No packages remain after filtering [ 'my-app' ]
```

My `lerna.json` file has this definitions:

```
"packages": [
    "app1",
    "some-package-with-my-app/*",
    "app2",
    "app3"
  ],
```

I also tried to run `lerna run --scope some-package-with-my-app/my-app test` but got the same error (with the corresponding filter name, of course)

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing something in the [docs](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/run#readme)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The package named `my-app` was scoped with my organisation name.
i.e. the name as appeared in my `package.json` file was `@org/my-app` so once running `lerna run --scope @org/my-app test` it worked perfectly